# What is the Rust equivalent of this C structure?

Tags: rust

I'm going through the Rust book and am on the ownership chapter. They have a sample of a car, and four wheels. The wheels know their owner (car), but the car doesn't know its wheels. That got me to thinking, what is the Rust equivalent of this C code?

```
struct Car;
struct Wheel {
    int size;
    struct Car *owner;
};

struct Car {
    char const *name;
    Wheel wheels[4];
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the literal answer would be:

```
struct Car {
    name: &'static str, // '
    wheels: [Wheel; 4],
}

struct Wheel {
    size: i32,
    owner: *mut Car,
}
```

But that's not *hugely* helpful since `owner` can't be used outside of `unsafe` code since it's a bare pointer.  This, however, gets to a limitation of Rust in that it's impossible in practice to have cyclic borrowed references; that is, you can't use a `&Car` for `owner`.

Which begs the question: what is it that you *really* want to express, here?  Does a `Wheel` *actually* need to know about the `Car` it's attached to?  If not, you could just drop `owner` and it'd all be fine.

If it does, can you live with `unsafe` blocks peppering your code (aside: this should generally be your option of last resort)?  If not, you need some notion of shared ownership.  In that case, do you only require read-only access to this structure?  If so, perhaps you want `Rc<Car>`.  If not, you might need `Rc<Cell<Car>>`... unless you're working in a threaded environment, in which case you'll need `Arc<Mutex<Car>>`... maybe.

I suppose what I'm getting at is: there's an *obvious*, direct equivalent, but if you're actually trying to port the semantics... you're going to need to be more specific about what you're trying to do, not *how* you're trying to do it.

Comment: This is all good information. In general, in Rust and C, I wouldn't write code like that, though it does come up on occasion. I was basically just wondering how to express an Owner/Ownee relationship in cases where the Ownee (wheel) needs to know about the Owner.

Comment: @njpaul You may want to read the [`std::rc` overview docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html). They have a good example of a owner-ownee relationship.